# Booking service problem

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on booking service.

I have a table where users enter their open hours. These pieces of information allow me to generate slot times for a particular day.

For example, for row one, I know that the user works on Monday morning between 10:00 am and 12:00 am and he proposes a service of 30 minutes.

We have 4 slots of 30 minutes each.

- 10:00 -> 10:30
- 10:30 -> 11:00
- 11:00 -> 11:30
- 11:30 -> 12:00

[image]

When I generate these slot times, I need to relate them to a particular day. For example **December 16, Monday.**

- 10:00 -> 10:30
- 10:30 -> 11:00
- 11:00 -> 11:30
- 11:30 -> 12:00

But I don't know how to do that. In my database, I know that the particular user works on Monday, but it's mean nothing for SQL. How can I generate that on a particular Monday?

For the moment, I don't have a lot of things to show...

I created this table, it represents the working hours of a User.

For example.

- Monday 10:00am to 12:00am
- Monday 3:00pm to 6:00pm

```
CREATE TABLE allow_day_and_time (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL
    workingday varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    start_time time NOT NULL,
    end_time time NOT NULL,
);
```

I had an idea, but I'm not sure if its the right way to do that...

1. Generate a series of days between **today** and a **random** end day.
2. Return the timestamps of all allowed days filled on allow_day_and_time table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetchWorkingDays()
 RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, workingday character varying, end_time time without time zone, start_time time without time zone)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
        day_ VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    FOR day_ IN
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(date_trunc('day', DD)::DATE, 'day')
    FROM
        generate_series(NOW()::timestamp, '2019-12-31'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) DD LOOP
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM allow_day_and_time WHERE allow_day_and_time.workingday = '_day';     
    END LOOP;
END;
$function$
```

Maybe, I was not clear in my explanation.

The main idea of this is to generate slot times by taking to account all constraints.

I don't want to record the availabilities in DB but record booking slots.

What're these constraints?

The user has working hours stocked in allow_days_and_times table (Which means that the user can work on Monday to 10:00 am to 3:00 pm for example).

Here the allow_days_and_times table

```
CREATE TABLE allow_day_and_time (
period_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
day VACHAR(50) NOT NULL,
start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
end_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

The user has blocked periods stocked in block_period table, like Christmas holidays for example.

Here the block_period table

```
CREATE TABLE block_period (
period_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
start_period TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
end_period TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

Finally, the user has theses booked times stocked in booked_slots

Here the booked_slots table

```
CREATE TABLE booked_slots (
booking_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
end_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

I've simplified as much as possible the table.

Okay, now, let's say I have an API in charge to find all free slots for a particular user. GET /api/user/xxx/availabilities

How can I generate all the availabilities for this user by taking to account all these constraints?